# Remove Backslashes from Json Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Remove Backslashes from JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery

```
var str = "{"data":"{\n \"taskNames\" : [\n \"01 Jan\",\n \"02 Jan\",\n \"03 Jan\",\n \"04 Jan\",\n \"05 Jan\",\n \"06 Jan\",\n \"07 Jan\",\n \"08 Jan\",\n \"09 Jan\",\n \"10 Jan\",\n \"11 Jan\",\n \"12 Jan\",\n \"13 Jan\",\n \"14 Jan\",\n \"15 Jan\",\n \"16 Jan\",\n \"17 Jan\",\n \"18 Jan\",\n \"19 Jan\",\n \"20 Jan\",\n \"21 Jan\",\n \"22 Jan\",\n \"23 Jan\",\n \"24 Jan\",\n \"25 Jan\",\n \"26 Jan\",\n \"27 Jan\"]}

var finalData = str.replace("\\", "");
```

but this does not work for me. Any help?

Comment: It looks like your Json data is invalid.

Comment: That's a syntax error. Many of your `"` aren't escaped.

Comment: okay, I was unable to load whole data of Json, its too large i have did some of the data

Comment: You need to not have them in the first place. It is a server issue, not a client issue

Comment: okay, but i receive this data, can you please provide the solution for this.

Comment: The code as you posted is invalid, so it is difficult to help you. Please explain *exactly how* you retrieve the JSON data and you are trying to process it.

Comment: hello Felix kling, I'm getting this data from enternal source which is sample json data i have to remove slashes from client to make proper json data

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your string is invalid, but assuming it was valid, you'd have to do:

```
var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

When you want to replace all the occurences with `.replace`, the first parameter must be a regex, if you supply a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced, that's why your replace wouldn't work.

Cheers

Comment: when i used the above i'm getting this error
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var finalData = taskNames.replace(/\\/g, "");

Comment: because in the code you're just providing there's no `str`, it's called `taskNames`

Comment: sorry my name convention was wrong I change but still getting same error Edgar

Comment: Great. The problem is that in js code you can't have line breaks in the middle of a string (in other languages, like php, you can). Here's the corrected solution: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/xPUT3/1/

Comment: Hey Edgar Thanks its working..!!, Will implement this.. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Just in case: If you need str to become a js object, just do `var obj = eval(str)` after the replace

Answer (score 54):

**tl;dr:** You don't have to remove the slashes, you have nested JSON, and hence have to  decode the JSON twice: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BPG2j/) (note I used double slashes in the example, because the JSON is inside a JS string literal).

---

I assume that your actual JSON looks like

```
{"data":"{\n \"taskNames\" : [\n \"01 Jan\",\n \"02 Jan\",\n \"03 Jan\",\n \"04 Jan\",\n \"05 Jan\",\n \"06 Jan\",\n \"07 Jan\",\n \"08 Jan\",\n \"09 Jan\",\n \"10 Jan\",\n \"11 Jan\",\n \"12 Jan\",\n \"13 Jan\",\n \"14 Jan\",\n \"15 Jan\",\n \"16 Jan\",\n \"17 Jan\",\n \"18 Jan\",\n \"19 Jan\",\n \"20 Jan\",\n \"21 Jan\",\n \"22 Jan\",\n \"23 Jan\",\n \"24 Jan\",\n \"25 Jan\",\n \"26 Jan\",\n \"27 Jan\"]}"}
```

I.e. you have a top level object with one key, `data`. The value of that key is a string containing JSON itself. This is usually because the server side code didn't properly create the JSON. That's why you see the `\"` inside the string. This lets the parser know that `"` is to be treated literally and doesn't terminate the string.

So you can either fix the server side code, so that you don't double encode the data, or you have to decode the JSON twice, e.g.

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(json).data));
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this `if (str.includes('\"')) { str = JSON.parse(str); }`

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: when i used the above i'm getting this error TypeError: str.replace is not a function [Break On This Error] var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, "");

Answer (score 2):

Try to do JSON.parse(data), it should work. In most cases when the JSON is generated from Sitecore or any backend, they will come with all the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deserialize the JSON once before returning it as response.
Please refer below code. This works for me:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Object finalData = jss.DeserializeObject(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Native , This worked for me

```
name = "hi \n\ruser"
name.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, ""); // hi user
```

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling for hours, this worked out. You can use this function to convert your json string with backslashes to a javascript object.

```
  function strToObj(str: string) {
    var obj = {};
    if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
      var objStr = str.match(/\{(.)+\}/g);
      eval('obj =' + objStr);
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.json))` did the work for  me.