# How can I remove the backslash in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i remove the back slash in below array ? while im concat the values im getting backslash how can i remove that ?

```
[{"album_desc":"","id":1,"album_title":"","album_creation_date":"2015-04-18T10:42:38.519Z","album_pics":["{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},"]}]
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$('.ImageName').append('{"media_type"'+':"'+ fileItem['_file']['type'] + '",'+'"last_modified_date"'+':"'+ new Date() + '",'+'"thumnail_pic_loc"'+':"'+ fileItem['_file']['name'] + '",'+'"large_pic_loc"'+':"'+ fileItem['_file']['name'] + '",'+'"filter_type"'+':"'+ fileItem['_file']['type'] + '",'+'"pic_id"' +':'+'"d5bd"}'+',');
```

Comment: I guess you are generating this using PHP ?

Comment: no im jquery @RohitBandooni

Comment: How do the backslashes get there in the first place?

Comment: Tried using jQuery.replace();  ??

Comment: Your other problem seems to be that you're trying to build JSON by hand. Make an object and then use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: how can i do that @juhana

Comment: 1) make an object 2) use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: please provide some code Im not aware of that check my jquery @Juhana

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using PHP's json_encode to create the JSON.

Your JSON *string* inside the "album_pics" array likely needs to be parsed using `JSON.parse()` into a JSON *object*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the backslashes with empty string, providing that `a` is this string:

```
a = '[{"album_desc":"","id":1,"album_title":"","album_creation_date":"2015-04-18T10:42:38.519Z","album_pics":["{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},"]}]';
console.log(a.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), ""));
```

Gives:

```
[{"album_desc":"","id":1,"album_title":"","album_creation_date":"2015-04-18T10:42:38.519Z","album_pics":["{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)","thumnail_pic_loc":"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg","large_pic_loc":"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"},{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)","thumnail_pic_loc":"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg","large_pic_loc":"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"},"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '[{"album_desc":"","id":1,"album_title":"","album_creation_date":"2015-04-18T10:42:38.519Z","album_pics":["{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_63901.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},{\"media_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"last_modified_date\":\"Sat Apr 18 2015 16:12:31 GMT+0530 (IST)\",\"thumnail_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"large_pic_loc\":\"LostFile_JPG_67677.jpg\",\"filter_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"pic_id\":\"d5bd\"},"]}]';
var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, "");
console.log(finalData);
```

[Remove Backslashes from Json Data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036626/remove-backslashes-from-json-data-in-javascript)

This might helps you :)