# ng-repeat is not allowing me to access JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json that throws a duplicate error. My json looks like:

```
    //console.log(json) shows it as 
    Object{
      IsCanceled: false
      IsCompleted: true
      Results: "{"folders": [{"name": "Hello", "age": 21},{"name": "World","age": 25}]}"
     }
```

I have tried:

```html
   //No error happen with this one but no data shows up as well
   <tr ng-repeat="f in Results.folders">
     <td>
      {{f.name}}
     </td> 
   </tr>
```

Also:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="f in Results">
    <td ng-repeat="s in f.folders">
     {{s.name}}
     </td> 
   </tr>
```

And Also:

```html
 //Considering all names are different 
 <tr ng-repeat="f in Results.folders track by f.name">
    <td>
      {{f.name}}
    </td> 
 </tr>
```

All of them throw an ng-repeat duplicates error and I can't figure out why.

ERROR MESSAGE:
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: s in sc.scans.Result, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: can you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: in your question json is not valid

Comment: I posted part of the object. I will add the other parts.

Comment: Did you parse your JSON?

Comment: I returned it from a ReadAsStringAsync() httpClient api call

Comment: Should I have parsed it before sending it to the view @jcubic

Comment: Of course you need to parse the json string before using it.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/NHcTTNvQq6SRLonXgW9Q?p=preview. if json is valid  there should not be error.

Comment: @jcubic I have parsed the JSON using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response); and now it looks like Result:""{\"folders\":[{\"name\": \"Hello\"}]

Comment: Backslashes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036626/remove-backslashes-from-json-data-in-javascript

Comment: You didn't parse it you serialize object to string, you need to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: First verify that data you want to display is valid javascript array. And then check if this data is accessible in view. You can always use this simple check: `<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>`.