# Print array with objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this array

```
"[{\"category_id\":\"2\",\"category_name\":\"Fun\"},
{\"category_id\":\"3\",\"category_name\":\"Science\"},
 {\"category_id\":\"4\",\"category_name\":\"Art\"},
{\"category_id\":\"5\",\"category_name\":\"Nature\"},...]"
```

i want to output this in user readable format

Comment: Put your code structure here then we can help you.

Comment: It is not an array. It’s a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Backslashes from Json Data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036626/remove-backslashes-from-json-data-in-javascript)

Comment: what does "user readable format" mean to you? Do you want us to just guess?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not an array. It’s a string.

Perhaps you mean

```
var x = "[{\"category_id\":\"2\",\"category_name\":\"Fun\"},{\"category_id\":\"3\",\"category_name\":\"Science\"},{\"category_id\":\"4\",\"category_name\":\"Art\"},{\"category_id\":\"5\",\"category_name\":\"Nature\"}]"

console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
   var obj = "[{\"category_id\":\"2\",\"category_name\":\"Fun\"},{\"category_id\":\"3\",\"category_name\":\"Science\"},{\"category_id\":\"4\",\"category_name\":\"Art\"},{\"category_id\":\"5\",\"category_name\":\"Nature\"},...]";

    obj = obj.replace(/\\/g, '');
    console.log(obj);
```